# Find points of Rectangle given two diagonal points and a normal in 3D

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vectors, 3d, rectangles

I'm developing a geometry framework in a program I'm working on that contains all the good stuff like vectors, points, lines, planes, polygons, etc.  I was attempting to create a rectangle object, but have run into a problem which is that there is little information available on deriving points of a rectangle with a minimal amount of information given.  When programming, the less provided the object, the more accurate the results.  So with this in mind, I was attempting to create a rectangle with only the following given:

- Two diagonal points
- Normal of the plane created by the rectangle.  There's still some room for error here, but should limit it since if upon a check that the normal is not indeed orthogonal to the line created by the two diagonal points, then I can throw an exception.

I thought I had it figured out, but evidently not.  If I define the four points in CCW direction as P<sub>0</sub>, P<sub>1</sub>, P<sub>2</sub>, and P<sub>3</sub>.  P<sub>0</sub> and P<sub>2</sub> are therefore given.  And **N** is the normal to the plane that will be defined by the rectangle.

Vector **V<sub>1</sub>**,  runs from P<sub>0</sub> to P<sub>1</sub>.  Vector **V<sub>2</sub>**,  runs from P<sub>1</sub> to P<sub>2</sub>.

**V<sub>1</sub>**, **V<sub>2</sub>**, and **N** should all be orthogonal to each other.  Therefore,

**V<sub>2</sub>**  = **N** x **V<sub>1</sub>**

And since

P<sub>2</sub> = P<sub>0</sub> + **V<sub>1</sub>** + **V<sub>2</sub>**

Then

P<sub>2</sub> = P<sub>0</sub> + **V<sub>1</sub>** + **N** x **V<sub>1</sub>**

This can be put into Ax=b form and using Cramer's rule find the values for each component of **V<sub>1</sub>**.

I'm ending up with some skewed results though that seem to be beyond rounding errors.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Life would be easier both for you and for the user of your library if you required one point and two orthogonal vectors to determine a rectangle. Alternatively, one point, two scalars, and a rotation.

Comment: My class actually has more than one overloaded constructor.  One of which does just that.  But I'm also trying to offer other ways.  As for one point, two scalars, and a rotation... that's got all the issues we've been addressing in this posting.

Comment: Not really. If you have one point $\mathbf p_0$, two scalars $\ell$ and $w$, and a $3\times 3$ rotation matrix $\mathbf R$, then you can define an $\ell\times w$ rectangle in the $xy$-plane $\mathbf q_0 = (0,0,0)^T$, $\mathbf q_1=(\ell,0,0)^T$, $\mathbf q_2=(\ell,w,0)^T$, $\mathbf q_3=(0,w,0)^T$, and set $\mathbf p_i = \mathbf p_0 + \mathbf R\mathbf q_i$.

Answer (score 1):

A single diagonal isn’t enough to identify a unique rectangle:

[image: ambiguous rectangles]

---

Adding the length of a side along with some convention as to which side it means isn’t the most efficient way to represent a rectangle, but let’s explore it a bit.

I always find it easier to work things out in a convenient coordinate system and then apply appropriate transformations to generalize. We’ll use the convention that the specified side is attached to the first point of the diagonal and that the diagonal is counterclockwise from it. So, let’s put our rectangle in the $xy$-plane with the first vertex at the origin and the known side along the $x$-axis:[image: rect with vectors]

The sides and diagonal form a Pythagorean triple, so in this coordinate system, $P_1=(s,\sqrt{d^2-s^2})$, where $s$ is the given side length and $d=\|P_1-P_0\|$, the length of the given diagonal. It shouldn’t be too hard to work out the transformation that’s required to move this rectangle into the required position. One thing that might make it easier is to first rotate so that the diagonal is along the $x$-axis: $\cos\theta=s/d$ and after applying a rotation through $-\theta$ we end up with $$\begin{align}
P_2 &= \left({s^2\over d},-\frac s d\sqrt{d^2-s^2}\right) \\
P_3 &= \left({d^2-s^2\over d},\frac s d\sqrt{d^2-s^2}\right)
\end{align}$$ for the missing corners.

---

Another possibility—again sticking with the diagonal—is to take advantage of the fact that the chords drawn from a point on a circle to the endpoints of a diameter form a right angle. Placing the known diagonal on the $x$-axis with its *midpoint* on the origin, you can locate the other corners with an angle $0<\theta<\pi$. The coordinates are simply $(\frac d2\cos\theta, \frac d2\sin\theta)$ and its negative. That might make the computations simpler, but it's hardly an intuitive way to specify a rectangle, I think.

---

Moving the rectangle into position is straightforward.

Translate so that $P_0$ is at the origin. We have the vector $\mathbf d=P_1-P_0$ for the diagonal, $\mathbf n$ for the normal, and the side length $\|\mathbf s\|$. The vectors $\mathbf d$ and $\mathbf d\times\mathbf n$ form an orthogonal basis for the plane of the rectangle. Using the result for the $xy$-plane from above and keeping in mind that the local coordinate system is left-handed, we get $$
\mathbf s = \|\mathbf s\|{\|\mathbf s\| \over \|\mathbf d\|}{\mathbf d\over\|\mathbf d\|} + \|\mathbf s\|{\sqrt{\|\mathbf d\|^2-\|\mathbf s\|^2}\over\|\mathbf d\|}{\mathbf d\times\mathbf n\over\|\mathbf d\times\mathbf n\|}
$$ for the vector representing side $P_0P_2$. Note that this construction doesn't require that $\mathbf n$ actually be normal to the rectangle, only that the above cross product lie in its plane.

Translating back to where the rectangle is supposed to be, we end up with $P_0+\mathbf s$ and $P_1-\mathbf s$ for the two missing corners. The “normal” vector clearly encodes redundant information. It could be replaced by an angle of rotation around the line defined by $\mathbf d$, bringing the number of pieces of information needed to specify a rectangle down to eight, but it would likely be simpler overall to specify it with a corner and vectors that define the two sides instead.

Comment: Ahh... I hadn't thought of that case.  I was thinking more in how the plane created from it would affect the results.  So what would you suggest?  I assume include a width or height.  I don't think angle makes a lot of sense.  And I'm not sure how to incorporate that.

Comment: You need to nail down one of the other corners somehow. The length of one of the sides would do it, but you’ll need to establish a convention for which side it means.

Comment: I'll be honest, I'm struggling to figure out how to get that point using the length of the line.  It took me a while as it is to figure out what I have.  How would you find the third point using the length of one of the sides?

Comment: The length by itself isn’t enough. You need to also know which of the vertices to measure from and which side of the diagonal it’ll be on. You can establish a convention for that, for instance, you measure from the first point of the pair on the side that makes a positive angle with the diagonal. This isn’t the most parsimonious representation, though. You’ve now got 10 quantities (two points, one vector and a length), but three corner points only need 9.

Comment: You're right.  The convention is not a problem.  But I still need to figure out how to put together all the pieces.  I'll keep scratching my head on it, but if something stands out as obvious, I'm all ears.

Comment: I think you’re better off with a point and two vectors. This gives a parallelogram in general. A rectangle is a special case for which the vectors are orthogonal. However, see the additions to my answer.

Comment: Brilliant approach!  I worked through the parameters and derived an alignment matrix I think should work.  I'll test it out on a real scenario soon and let you know. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Well, I tried this and it did and didn't work.  Using the coordinates defined in R2 on the xy plane, I just created a basic rectangle.  And then applied three transformation matrices to it.  I'll  post in a solution to follow.  Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @bjhuffine If you use $3\times3$ matrices to represent the transformations, you can’t represent translations with them, so the $xy$-plane rectangle has to be built somewhere other than the origin.

Comment: I'm using affine transformations for that very reason.  Basically, I create the basic rectangle on the xy-plane, use an alignment transformation to align the diagonal vector, recalculate the new normal, apply a new alignment transformation to align the normals, then apply the translation transformation.  Actually the last two are combined, but in either case it required two alignment transformations.